# Need to create a datastructure similar to HashSet but should have frequency of elements contained

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

An array is there from which I need to pick the elements and store the element in the HashSet like structure as well as its frequency ie the number of times the element is there in the array.The other requirement is that the class should support operation of set intersection.
What would be the better approach to do so :-

```
class myHashSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> implements Set<E>// I dont think I need the serilizability and cloneability{
   //and then override the methods here
}
```

or

```
class myHashSet<E> exetnds HashSet<E>{

    // and then just override the add method like so
    public boolean More ...add(E e) {
        Integer count = map.get(temp);
        map.put(temp, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
        return true;
   }
 }
```

or write my own class myHashSet without any reference to these preexisting classes.

Comment: Looks like you need a [`MultiSet`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset)...

Comment: The constraint don't permit me to use anything other than Java. I guess I need to tweak preexisting class in collection framework or come up with my own class.

Comment: The way to make a multi set without using guava is a `HashMap<E, Integer>` where the values are frequencies.

Comment: Ok Got the idea, but please elaborate little further.

Comment: If this is for homework, please try the suggestion of using a map of object to frequency count as @pbabcdefp suggested. Add your code if it doesn't work or you have other issues.

Comment: I agree with @GiovanniBotta but the one hint I would give is that you should write `extends AbstractCollection<E>` not `AbstractSet<E>`.

Comment: No I extended the AbstractSet<E> since by using this datastructure I would check the intersection of elements in another array. Sorry I did n't mention that initially, should I be extending AbstractCollection<E> still !!

Comment: The important part is that your class implements the `Set` interface. Extending `AbstractSet` makes sense to me since it contains useful methods that will simplify the implementation.

Comment: Thanks Should Be able to create it now.

Answer (score 1):

My current understanding is that a wrapper Set can be enough which delegates all the interface calls to the wrapped Set instance and also maintains a map with the multiplicities. The multiplicity behavior is not clear to me, this is why I have put the TODO-s in the code with the multiplicity registry map.

```
public class MyHashSet<E> implements Set<E> {
    // element registration
    private final Set<E> mySet = new HashSet<E>();
    // multiplicity registration
    private final Map<E, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<E, Integer>();

    public int size() {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.isEmpty();
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.contains(o);
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.iterator();
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.toArray();
    }

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.toArray(a);
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.add(e);
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.remove(o);
    }

    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.containsAll(c);
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.addAll(c);
    }

    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.retainAll(c);
    }

    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.removeAll(c);
    }

    public void clear() {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        mySet.clear();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.equals(o);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Consider the role of myMap
        return mySet.hashCode();
    }
}
```